# Rake not executing some tasks, mistakenly says "Invoke <task>s (first_time, not_needed)"

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

I am creating a rakefile to automate some tasks. I have a pretty basic rake task set up that I'd like to call `:run`:

```
desc "Run instances in the runs directory"
task :run, [:filter] do |t, args|
  args.with_defaults(:filter => "*")
  runs = Dir["runs/"+args.filter]
  puts "Running " + runs.length.to_s + " instances..."
  for run_path in runs
    run(run_path)
  end
end
```

Pretty simple, right!?

- I type `rake run` and the run function is called for all paths.
- `rake run["*"]` gives the same result, as expected.
- `rake run["nothing"]` runs nothing, as expected (I have no files named "nothing"). It prints `Running 0 instances...`
- `rake run["*real-file-name*"]` does nothing! Even though the file name should be a match, it doesn't even hit the `puts` statement.
- `rake run["TEST"]` does nothing! It also doesn't print `Running 0 instances...` like it should (like "nothing", "TEST" doesn't exist), but it doesn't hit the puts statement. Oddly, `rake run["TE"]` and `rake run["ST"]` both work.

For the cases that don't work, adding the trace flag (`-t`) gives the following output:

```
** Invoke runs (first_time, not_needed)
```

For cases that do work, I get:

```
** Invoke run (first_time)
** Execute run
```

Notice the cases that don't work are invoking `runs`. plural. Even though I specify it as `run`. What the heck is going on here?

**Update:**
I noticed that this happens when I run the rakefile in some directories, but not others.

Using:

- ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13) [i386-mingw32]
- rake, version 10.4.2
- Window 7

Comment: No luck. I posted an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ruby/rake/issues/69), but no one else can repeat the problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding. In my case, I reinstalled rake and other involved tasks, opened a new terminal ... and the error went away. Really weird.